# how to create a vector of pointers to a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a pointer to a vector:

```
vector<double> mv;
mv.push_back(233);
mv.push_back(234);
mv.push_back(654);
vector<double>* new_mv_pt = new vector<double> (3);
new_mv_pt = &mv;    

cout << (*new_mv_pt)[1] << endl;
```

How can I make another vector that will store this pointer to a vector? 
I was trying this...

```
    vector<double*> vop = new vector<double> (3);

vop.push_back(*new_mv_pt);

cout << (*vop)[1] << endl;
```

but it did not work. Is what I am attempting even possible?:

Comment: First, get your answer.  Second, realize that this is a horrible idea because you are eliminating the vector's ability to manage memory for you, which is (at least) half the point of using it in the first place.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out why he has a pointer to a vector in the first place. It makes no conceptual sense to be doing it like this, especially if it's in the same function / class.

Answer (score 7):

Whoa, slow down there!

You're doing some pretty crazy things with your memory, so let's start from the beginning.

You have a single vector that has 3 elements in it. You want to reference that vector using a pointer. Let's see how that looks:

```
vector<double> mv;
mv.push_back(233);
mv.push_back(234);
mv.push_back(654);
// No no no no! You don't have to `new` a pointer that 
// you're going to assign to something else!
// This is called a memory leak, and it means you've just wasted (!!!)
// C++ memory! Don't do it 
// vector<double>* new_mv_pt = new vector<double> (3);
// Instead, do this:
vector<double>* ptr_to_mv = &mv; // No leak, immediately points to a vector<double> mv;
```

That takes care of the first bit. Now, let's get into it a bit deeper. You want to store a vector of references to vectors. Alright, that sounds fair. There's a few ways to go about it. Let's go back to the example of `mv` and other things:

```
vector<double> mv;
mv.push_back(233);
mv.push_back(234);
mv.push_back(654);
vector<double>* ptr_to_mv = &mv;
// So far so good. Now, based on your question, you want
// to have a list of these to point to. So:
vector<vector<double>*> vop;
vop.push_back( ptr_to_mv ); // All clean.
```

At this point in your code, you have to access `vop` with `.at()` or the `operator[]` to get to a `vector<double>*`, then you dereference it with `*` or use `->` to work on it directly:

```
std::vector<double>* ptr_to_vector = vop[0]; // Got my pointer
std::cout << ptr_to_vector->at( 0 ) << std::endl; // Prints '233'
```

This prints 233 because all of this is you referencing `mv`. In a comment in another answer, you said that when you delete these pointers, you get an assertion. *This is supposed to happen, because you're deleting things twice!*

Remember `mv`, that you declared a long time ago? Well, you didn't make it a dynamic vector.You didn't `new` it, and it's no pointer. So when the function exits, it will automatically delete itself - it will call its destructor and ***die on the stack***. If you look at `ptr_to_vector` or `ptr_to_mv`, they're all referencing `mv`, which cleans itself.

***If you call delete on it, you're trying to call delete on `mv` (that's what you're pointing to) and you're double-deleting!***

So, when you have a pointer to `mv`, don't delete it. It's a stack-based variable. It will clean itself up.

***Still following? Great, let's get into it a bit more:***

Now, if there's a *reason* you need to `new` up a vector, you don't assign override it with an old pointer (as I told you before, you'll leave memory). You make a completely fresh new pointer:

```
// Our vector of double vector pointers
vector<vector<double>*> vop;

vector<double> mv;
mv.push_back(233);
mv.push_back(234);
mv.push_back(654);

// References a stack variable: don't delete
vector<double>* ptr_to_mv = &mv;
vop.push_back( ptr_to_mv );

// Makes a fresh copy of mv. You must delete this
// manually
vector<double>* fresh_ptr = new vector<double>( mv );
(*fresh_ptr)[0] = 1337;
// changes only data in fresh_ptr, not `mv`
vop.push_back( fresh_ptr );

/* Blah blah blah, work */
// Functions about to exit, gotta clean up!
delete fresh_ptr;
//delete ptr_to_mv; // NO.
//delete vop[0]; // NO!
//delete vop[1]; // ... Already deleted from fresh_ptr
// ... This is going to get tedious if we don't have a fresh_ptr
// for every vector we need!
```

The above shows the problem: we have 2 pointers, both inside `vop`, where one needs to be cleaned up by calling delete, and another that doesn't because it's just a reference to `mv`, which cleans automatically! Looping over the vector and deleting everything will cause that nasty assertion to happen. How do we deal with it and still get the clean up we need?

Dirty and Quick Solution 1 is to just `delete vop[1]`/`fresh_ptr` and be done with it. The better solution is that, whenever you `new` up a resource, you wrap it up in this wonderful thing called a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). The code will look like this:

```
// Our vector of double vector pointers. Non-owning
vector<vector<double>*> vop;

vector<double> mv;
mv.push_back(233);
mv.push_back(234);
mv.push_back(654);

// References a stack variable: don't delete
vector<double>* ptr_to_mv = &mv;
vop.push_back( ptr_to_mv );

// Makes a fresh copy of mv
// puts it inside a std::unique_ptr,
// which, like a stack-based vector,
// can clean itself up
std::unique_ptr<vector<double>> fresh_ptr( new vector<double>( mv ) );
vop.push_back( fresh_ptr.get() );

/* Blah blah blah, work */
// Functions about to exit, gotta clean up!
//delete fresh_ptr; // Not necessary
//delete ptr_to_mv; // Nope.jpg
```

And there you go, remove all that commented-out code and suddenly, your stuff is clean as a whistle!

Of course, now, the final question I have for you is:
***What the hell are you doing that requires all these pointers to pointers to references of pointers of vectors?***

Comment: This was extremely helpful. You tought me alot. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is an incredibly detailed answer to a very simple question. You sir are a pro! +1

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you need to do this:

```
vector<vector<double>*> vop;
```

Because you are looking for a list of vector pointers.

What you have here:

```
vector<double *> vop
```

is just a vector of `double` pointers.

Also you will just want this:

```
vop.push_back(new_mv_pt); //  <- No asterisk (you don't want to de-reference it)
```

Comment: How would I go about deleting both pointers to avoid a leak in memory? I try deleting new_mv_pt and I get some kind of assertion error on run time. What's the problem?

Comment: What do you mean both pointers? do you mean `new_mv_pt` and the one in the vector?

Comment: Well when I try deleting new_mv_pt without being in the vector of pointers, it won't work and comes up with some kind of assertion error at run time. In the end I would like to know how to delete all of it safely.

Answer (score 2):

You have a memory leak here:

```
vector<double>* new_mv_pt = new vector<double> (3);
new_mv_pt = &mv;
```

You're creating a `vector<double>` on the heap, storing it's address in `new_mv_pt`, and then *overwriting* that address with the address of `mv`. The `vector<double>` still exists on the heap, but you have permanently lost its address (and therefore have no way to `delete` it or do anything else with it).

This code:

```
vector<double*> vop = new vector<double> (3);
vop.push_back(*new_mv_pt);
cout << (*vop)[1] << endl;
```

Does not work because `vop` is a vector of `double*`s, and you are trying to insert a `vector<double>` into it. See [Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16026445/1227469) for the correct approach.